# Google Image Search - New tab

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

Ever since Google's new Image Search format, it's not respecting my "**Open each selected result in a new browser window**." setting. When I click on an image, it will open the selected link in a new tab, but will also open the link in the existing tab. I've been stuck at doing right clicks to open in a new tab.

This happens with Chrome & Firefox. I'm running Win7 x32 if that makes a difference.

Regular Google search still works as it should.

Any way to get this working again?